# How can I find hole in a 2D matrix?

Tags: algorithm, search, flood-fill

I know the title seems kind of ambiguous and for this reason I've attached an image which will be helpful to understand the problem clearly. I need to find holes inside the white region. A hole is defined as one or many cells with value '0' inside the white region I mean it'll have to be fully enclosed by cell's with value '1' (e.g. here we can see three holes marked as 1, 2 and 3). I've come up with a pretty naive solution:
1. Search the whole matrix for cells with value '0'
2. Run a DFS(Flood-Fill) when such a cell (black one) is encountered and check whether we can touch the boundary of the main rectangular region 
3. If we can touch boundary during DFS then it's not a hole and if we can't reach boundary then it'll be considered as a hole

Now, this solution works but I was wondering if there's any other efficient/fast solution for this problem.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How do you want to return the information about the holes?  Do you want a list of the cells that are in holes?  Do you want them grouped by which hole they are in?  Or do you just need to know if there are holes at all, or how many holes there are?  Or perhaps you need one representative cell for each hole.  Or do you just want to be able to specify a cell coordinate and ask whether that cell is in a hole?  Or maybe you want another 2D matrix as output, where each cell is flagged as either “hole” or “not-hole”.

Comment: The output should be both: 1. If there's any hole 2. The cell's in a hole should also be flagged so that I can understand this cell is in a hole. I mean I'm free to modify the input buffer to mark holes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**With floodfill, which you already have**: run along the BORDER of your matrix and floodfill it, i.e.,
change all zeroes (black) to 2 (filled black) and ones to 3 (filled white); ignore 2 and 3's that come from an earlier floodfill.

For example with your matrix, you start from the upper left, and floodfill black a zone with area 11. Then you move right, and find a black cell that you just filled. Move right again and find a white area, very large (actually all the white in your matrix). Floodfill it. Then you move right again, another fresh black area that runs along the whole upper and right borders. Moving around, you now find two white cells that you filled earlier and skip them. And finally you find the black area along the bottom border.

Counting the number of colours you found and set might already supply the information on whethere there *are* holes in the matrix.

Otherwise, or to find where they are, scan the matrix: all areas you find that are still of color 0 are holes in the black. You might also have holes in the white.

**Another method, sort of "arrested flood fill"**

Run all around the border of the first matrix. Where you find "0", you set
to "2". Where you find "1", you set to "3".

Now run around the new inner border (those cells that touch the border you have just scanned).
Zero cells touching 2's become 2, 1 cells touching 3 become 3.

You will have to scan twice, once clockwise, once counterclockwise, checking the cells "outwards" and "before" the current cell. That is because you might find something like this:

```
22222222222333333
2AB11111111C
31
```

Cell A is actually 1. You examine its neighbours and you find 1 (but it's useless to check *that* since you haven't processed it yet, so you can't know if it's a 1 or should be a 3 - which is the case, by the way), 2 and 2. A 2 can't change a 1, so cell A remains 1. The same goes with cell B which is again a 1, and so on. When you arrive at cell C, you discover that it is a 1, and has a 3 neighbour, so it toggles to 3... but *all the cells from A to C should now toggle*.

The simplest, albeit not most efficient, way to deal with this is to scan the cells clockwise, which gives you the *wrong* answer (C and D are 1's, by the way)

```
22222222222333333
211111111DC333333
33
```

and then scan them again counterclockwise. Now when you arrive to cell C, it has a 3-neighbour and toggles to 3. Next you inspect cell D, whose previous-neighbour is C, which is now 3, so D toggles to 3 again. In the end you get the correct answer

```
22222222222333333
23333333333333333
33
```

and for each cell you examined two neighbours going clockwise, one going counterclockwise. Moreover, one of the neighbours is actually *the cell you checked just before*, so you can keep it in a ready variable and save one matrix access.

If you find that you scanned a whole border without *even once* toggling a single cell, you can halt the procedure. Checking this will cost you 2(W*H) operations, so it is only really worthwhile if there are *lots* of holes.

In at most W*H*2 steps, you should be done.

**You might also want to check the Percolation Algorithm and try to adapt that one.**

Comment: I think "Arrested Flood-Fill" one is the best solution by far. I'm going to go with that with a little tweak. The steps are:
1. Any cell sharing the boundary of the main rectangle is a non-hole cell and marked as 2.
2. Now, instead of double scanning I'll just check the four neighbours I mean for (x,y) I'll check (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x+1,y) and (x,y-1). If any one of these neighbours is a non-hole cell then (x,y) MUST also be a non-hole cell and marked as 2. We can simply ignore white cells for this case.

Comment: 3. Lastly if we encounter a black cell whose neighbours are non-hole/white then it'll be a hole cell for sure and we can start flood-filling and mark all the cells of the hole as 3. 
4. After finishing a flood-fill we'll have to continue from step 2.

The main key to this approach is "A hole-cell cannot be a neighbour of a non-hole cell."

Thank you very much for your solution and of course let me know if you see any flaw in my approach.

Comment: You would actually only need two neighbours: the one which lies inside the outer border, and the one that you scanned "just before" the current step. There's a problem that requires additional steps, but it doesn't fit in this comment :-) -- so, adding to the answer...

Comment: Umm... okay I'm looking into it

Comment: Can you please explain the term "the one which lies inside the outer border" a little more? I think you're talking about the neighbours (x-1,y) and (x,y-1). Am I correct? If so then I think I got it.

Comment: Yes. When you complete a border, that becomes the "outer border" and you start working to the inner border. Depending on where you are in the inner border, the outer border could be (x, y-1) if you are on the top, (x+1,y) if you are on the right side, (x, y+1) if you are on the bottom, or (x-1, y). You can do that with four IFs, or better, implement the four sides as separate loops, and the corners as special cases.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks again for the wonderful explanation :)

Comment: I may have misunderstood the algorithm,  but I run into an issue if you are looking to use this to identify full holes, on an image like this: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/files.dotlearn.org/random/before+example.png,  the algorithm spits out something like this: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/files.dotlearn.org/random/after+example.png . It seems you would need to re-run through the whole matrix, in reverse order, (from in to out) again going twice for each sweep, in order to fully identify pixels that are part of holes, and those which are connected to the border (runtime 4*W*H)

Comment: @sam are you sure you used floodfill? It should have filled the whole black area...

Answer (score 3):

Make some sort of a "LinkedCells" class that will store cells that are linked with each other. Then check cells on-by-one in a from-left-to-right-from-top-to-bottom order, making the following check for each cell: if it's neighbouring cell is black - add this cell to that cell's group. Else you should create new group for this cell. You should only check for top and left neighbour.
**UPD:**  Sorry, I forgot about merging groups: if both neighbouring cells are black and are from different groups - you should merege tha groups in one.

Your "LinkedCells" class should have a flag if it is connected to the edge. It is false by default and can be changed to true if you add edge cell to this group. In case of merging two groups you should set new flag as a `||` of previous flags.
In the end you will have a set of groups and each group having false connection flag will be "hole".

This algorithm will be O(x*y).

Comment: A cell might be connected to both its left neighbor and its top neighbor, and those neighbors might themselves have been assigned to different groups.  So now you must merge those two groups, which means visiting cells more than once, which means the running time is greater than O(x*y).

Comment: An efficient way to do this, that includes merging groups, is the union-find algorithm.  Google it for lots of info.  But it's still more than O(x*y).

Comment: Yep, I forgot about it and updated my answer. Since merging can be done in a constant time, the complexity remains to be O(x*y).

Comment: @Chechulin: Thanks for the solution. I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: If you do merging in constant time, then finding group membership requires non-constant time.  You're just putting off the extra work.  It still has to be done to determine whether a cell is in a hole.

Comment: You can use FindUnion to make the merging O(log-star n)

Comment: @rob mayoff, finding groups is also a constant time. All you need is to have a link from a `Cell` object to the group that contains it.

Comment: Then merging groups takes time proportional to the size of one of the groups, because you have to update the group pointer of every cell in one of the groups being merged.

Comment: You can always use linked list.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the grid as a graph with individual cells as vertexes and edges occurring between adjacent vertexes. Then you can use Breadth First Search or Depth First Search to start at each of the cells, on the sides. As you will only find the components connected to the sides, the black cells which have not been visited are the holes. You can use the search algorithm again to divide the holes into distinct components.

EDIT: Worst case complexity must be linear to the number of cells, otherwise, give some input to the algorithm, check which cells (as you're sublinear, there will be big unvisited spots) the algorithm hasn't looked into and put a hole in there. Now you've got an input for which the algorithm doesn't find one of the holes.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but wouldn't that be almost same as my solution in terms of algorithmic complexity?

Comment: Yea, linear. You can't get better than linear: if an algorithm was sublinear, I can put the hole in the cells that haven't been visited by the algorithm and the algorithm will not be able to find them.

Comment: You care about pessimistic complexity, right? Not average? You didn't mention which one in your question...

Comment: because if you care about average complexity and you need to find ANY hole (not all holes) then there is some room for improvement.

Comment: Yeah, just the worst case as I need to find all the holes and flag every cell

Comment: @0x90 Yes, time is `O(N*M)` and the input data size is also `N*M` so it's linear.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is globally Ok. It's just a matter of optimizing it by merging the flood fill exploration with the cell scanning. This will just minimize tests.

The general idea is to perform the flood fill exploration line by line while scanning the table. So you'll have multiple parallel flood fill that you have to keep track of.

The table is then processed row by row from top to bottom, and each row processed from right to left. The order is arbitrary, could be reverse if you prefer.

Let *segments* identify a sequence of consecutive cells with value 0 in a row. You only need the index of the first and last cell with value 0 to define a segment. 
As you may guess a segment is also a flood fill in progress. So we'll add an identification number to the segments to distinguish between the different flood fills.

The nice thing of this algorithm is that you only need to keep track of segments and their identification number in row i and i-1. So that when you process row i, you have the list of segments found in the row i-1 and their associated identification number.

You then have to process segment connection in row i and row i-1. I'll explain below how this can be made efficient.

For now you have to consider three cases:

1. found a segment in row i not connected to a segment in row i-1. Assign it a new hole identification (incremented integer). If it's connected to the border of the table, make this number negative.
2. found a segment in row i-1 not connected to a segment in row i-1. You found the lowest segment of a hole. If it has a negative identification number it is connected to the border and you can ignore it. Otherwise, congratulation, you found a hole.
3. found a segment in row i connected to one or more segments in row i-1. Set the identification number of all these connected segments to the smallest identification number. See the following possible use case.

```
row i-1:   2  333 444 111
row i  :  ****  *** ***
```

The segments in row i should all get the value 1 identifying the same flood fill.

Matching segments in rows i and row i-1 can be done efficiently by keeping them in order from left to right and comparing segments indexes.

Process segments by lowest start index first. Then check if it's connected to the segment with lowest start index of the other row. If no, process case 1 or 2. Otherwise continue identifying connected segments, keeping track of the smallest identification number. When no more connected segments is found, set the identification number of all connected segments found in row i to the smallest identification value.

Index comparison for connectivity test can by optimized by storing (first-1,last) as segment definition since segments may be connected by their corners. You then can directly compare indexes bare value and detect overlapping segments.

The rule to pick the smallest identification number ensures that you automatically get the negative number for connected segments and at least one connected to the border. It propagates to other segments and flood fills.

This is a nice exercise to program. You didn't specify the exact output you need. So this is also left as exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Actually I need to determine if there's any hole in a white region. I also need to flag the hole regions so that I can understand whether any cell belongs to a hole or non-hole region.

Comment: This algorithm will tell you if there is any hole in a white region. If you need only to return a boolean, you may return true when you find the first hole. If it's not connected to a border, it's inside a white region. How do you need the flagging ? One easy method is to build linked lists of connected segments. You then have a relatively compact representation of a hole. You can use it to set a hole number value in cells belonging to each hole.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force algorithm as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793273/java-hole-in-grid) is as follow.

We now assume we can write in cells a value different from 0 or 1.

You need a flood fill functions receiving the coordinates of a cell to start from and an integer value to write into all connected cells holding the value 0.

Since you need to only consider holes (cells with value 0 surrounded by cells with value 1), you have to use two pass.

A first pass visit only cells touching the border. For every cell containing the value 0, you do a flood fill with the value -1. This tells you that this cell has a value different of 1 and has a connection to the border. After this scan, all cells with a value 0 belong to one or more holes.

To distinguish between different holes, you need the second scan. You then scan the remaining cells in the rectangle (1,1)x(n-2,n-2) you didn't scan yet. Whenever your scan hit a cell with value 0, you discovered a new hole. You then flood fill this hole with the integer of your choice to distinguish it from the others. After that you proceed with the scan until all cells have been visited.

When done, you may replace the values -1 with 0 because there shouldn't be any 0 left.

This algorithm works, but is not as efficient as the other algorithm I propose. Its advantage is that it's simple and doesn't need an extra data storage to hold the segments, hole identification and eventual segment chaining reference.