# FloodFill Function call not working

Tags: c

I had to use for the first time flood fill algorithm in order to solve a task from a homework. The main problem is that it seems that the call of the flood fill function I wrote doesn`t work.

My task is something very similar to the one described here:
[How can I find hole in a 2D matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230485/how-can-i-find-hole-in-a-2d-matrix)

I used an algorithm from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm and I adapted it to what I need.

I have for example this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And I want to transform it in something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 3 0
0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 3 0
0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 0
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and also to count the elements of every "area" or cluster.

In the main program, I search for the first element equal to 1 and send his position (x,y) to the function "color" (flood fill function) to become the "seed".

I tried to find the bugs using gdb - found nothing.
I added some printf() to the code to see what is happening - everything works fine until I call the function "color" and then nothing happens. 
I searched the internet for a solution but I didn`t find something to solve this.

Here is the code of the flood-fill:

```
int color(int x,int y,int n,int**sim,int nr, int h, int w)
{
if (x < h && y < w)
if( sim[x][y] == 1 )
    { 
    sim[x][y] = n;
    printf ("%d %d   ", x, y);//it does not print anything here

    if (sim[x-1][y] != 1 && sim[x+1][y] != 1 && sim[x][y-1] != 1 && sim[x][y+1] != 1)
        return nr; /*this happens when everything around is equal to 0 or n, so there is nothing to modify and the program should end*/
    else
        {
            nr++;
            color(x-1,y,n,sim,nr,h,w);
            color(x+1,y,n,sim,nr,h,w);
            color(x,y-1,n,sim,nr,h,w);
            color(x,y+1,n,sim,nr,h,w);
        }
    }
}
```

And the call in the main function:

```
int **s;
s = malloc(m*sizeof(int *));
for(i=1; i <= h; i++)
    s[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
a=0;
b=0;
while (a <= h && b <= w)
    {
    k = 0;
    for(i=a; i < h && k == 0; i++)
        for(j=b; j < w; j++)
            if( s[i][j] == 1 ) //find the first element = 1 and stop to its position
                {k = 1; printf("%d %d ", i, j);}
    printf("\n");
    if(k == 1)
        {
        a = i;
        b = j;
        nr = color(i,j,c,s,0,h,w); //call the function
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d ", k, c, i, j);
        cluster[c] = nr;
        c++;
        }
    if (k == 0)
        break; //if it is no area left to modify
    }
```

I am a beginner and I have never used flood fill before.  I am not even sure what is wrong: the flood fill code, the call of the function, or the way I pass the matrix sim[][] in the function.  What is wrong?

Comment: What is `m`? You have used `m` to allocate memory for both the width and the height of the array, but the array in your example is not square. I would allocate memory for `h` rows each of width `w`. I would use loops which index the array by 0..(h-1) and by 0..(w-1). In the `color()` function, I would check the indexing bounds, because the recursion can pass indices out of the array bounds.

Comment: In general, be wary of all **examples** you copy from the internet. That applies with equal vigor to [**codproject.com**](http://www.codeproject.com). Many examples you find will simply be incorrect, or contain significant errors.

Comment: m is the maximum number of rows and columns a matrix can have. Initially I allocated memory for h rows and w columns but i got Segmentation fault (core dumped)...i checked with gdb and that gave me something like:"3996 malloc.c: No such file or directory." It works only when I allocate m. I don`t know why it doesn`t let me to allocate less.

Comment: Probably because you aren't checking the array bounds. And BTW `color()` should return a value.

Comment: I changed the code so that everything starts from 0 to h-1 or w-1. I also added a condition in the color() so that it checks that x < h and    y < w.Same thing. color() is type int so it should be able to return int. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Did you mean `x < w` and `y < h`? And the four `color()` recursive statements don't use its return value.

Comment: It was x < h and y < w. Btw, the code you wrote is working. I saw where were my mistakes...the big one with (nr) and the others. Thanks a lot for helping me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous errors in the OP code, for example using the H and V array directions interchanged, and not checking the array bounds to prevent the recursion travelling off the edge of the array to continue wherever it happens to find a '1', or worse, accessing memory with an undefined pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define h  11   // height
#define w  10   // width

void color(int x, int y, int n, int **sim, int *nr) {
    if (x>=0 && x<w && y>=0 && y<h && n>1) {
        if( sim[y][x] == 1 ) { 
            sim[y][x] = n;
            (*nr)++;
            color(x-1, y,   n, sim, nr);
            color(x+1, y,   n, sim, nr);
            color(x,   y-1, n, sim, nr);
            color(x,   y+1, n, sim, nr);
        }
    }
}

void show(int **sim) {
    int i, j;
    for (j=0; j<h; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<w; i++) {
            printf ("%3d", sim[j][i]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main() {
    int **s;
    int n, i, j, nr;
    s = malloc(h*sizeof(int *));
    for(j=0; j<h; j++)
        s[j] = malloc(w*sizeof(int));
    for (j=0; j<h; j++)
        for (i=0; i<w; i++)
            s[j][i] = rand() % 2;
    show(s);

    n = 2;
    for (j=0; j<h; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<w; i++) {
            if (s[j][i] == 1) {
                nr = 0;
                color(i, j, n, s, &nr);
                printf("%3d,%3d,%3d,%3d\n", i, j, n, nr);
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    show(s);

    for(i=h-1; i>=0; i--)
        free (s[i]);
    free (s);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output.

```
1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0
1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0
1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0

0,  0,  2, 32
8,  1,  3,  1
9,  2,  4,  1
2,  3,  5,  1
1,  6,  6,  8
3,  7,  7,  1
7,  7,  8,  6
3,  9,  9,  2
6, 10, 10,  1

2  2  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0
2  2  2  2  2  2  2  0  3  0
2  0  0  2  0  0  2  0  0  4
2  0  5  0  2  0  2  2  2  0
2  2  0  2  2  0  2  2  2  0
2  0  0  2  2  2  2  2  2  0
0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  6  0  7  0  0  0  8  8  0
6  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0
0  6  0  9  9  0  0  0  8  8
6  6  6  0  0  0 10  0  8  0
```